# ruby split string into array then split array elements into words

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to perform deeper array method on a given string. Let's say I have `str = "hello world"`

I can split it using `str.split(" ")`. But my intended goal is to turn `"hello"` into `["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]` and `"world"` into `["w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]` so I can do array method of my choosing (like swapping first and last letter `["o", "e", "l", "l", "h"]`, and then returning it back into `["oellh", "dorlw"]`, and finally putting them back together `"oellh dorlw"`.

That's just an example method. There are several different array method I wish to apply, but it only works if the string is split into array of words, and further split into array of elements (`str.chars` is not what I am looking for). I tried `str.split(" ").each {|arr| arr.split("")}` but it does not work. What is the best method to split a string into an array, and splitting that array of words into array of elements, apply a method, and join them back into a string?

Comment: use `join` to join an array of strings. If you don't want to use `chars` then maybe use `str.split('')` but this includes the space as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"hello world".split.map { |word| word[-1] + word[1..-2] + word[0] }.join(' ')
=> "oellh dorlw"
```

Comment: Very simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really simple thing to do:

```
'hello world'.split.map{ |s|
  s[0], s[-1] = s[-1], s[0]
  s
} # => ["oellh", "dorlw"]
.join(' ') # => "oellh dorlw"
```

You don't need to create intermediate arrays of the word characters, which is  a waste of CPU. Instead, `s[0], s[-1] = s[-1], s[0]` is using parallel assignment to swap the first and last characters.

Once you have the array of reversed words then `join(' ')` will return you to a string again.

You could use `[...] * ' '` to accomplish the same thing but it's not as idiomatic:

```
["oellh", "dorlw"] * ' ' # => "oellh dorlw"
```

How that works is left for you to figure out.

If you want to convert a string into its characters, you *can* use `split('')`. `chars` is available and will do the same thing:

```
'hello world'.split.map(&:chars)  # => [["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"], ["w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]]
```

`chars` should be a tiny bit faster because Ruby isn't having to figure out what parameter was passed to `split`.

You can fold, spindle or mutilate all you want at that point.

I'd recommend reading through the Ruby class documentation a couple times. It'll help make you aware of what methods are available, so you can quickly search for these things.

Answer (score 2):

You almost have your own answer, you are just slightly off:

```
str = "hello world"
=> "hello world"
str.split(" ").map { |s| s.split("") }
=> [["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"], ["w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]]
```

Use `map` instead of `each`.

The reverse:

```
a = str.split(" ").map { |s| s.split("") }
=> [["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"], ["w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]]
a.map { |s| s.join }.join(" ")
=> "hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

To produce `["oellh", "dorlw"]` you can write

```
str.split(" ").map{|arr| arr.reverse}
```

To produce an array of arrays like

```
[["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"], ["w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]]
```

you can do

```
str.split(" ").map{|arr| arr.split("")}
```